# Can't understand layout idea using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to layout a simple web application that i am building using CSS grid.

I need help understanding where I am going wrong with the CSS grid. for some reason the browser is crossing out the css grid rules that I am defining.

[Firefox Developer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjkOI.png)

Also see my code for both HTML and CSS

[HTML Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK3x2.png)

```
    /* Main Container */
.ipad {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 1024px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 3fr;
}

/* 
Grid Layout */
.firstbox {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    grid-column-start: 1fr;
    grid-column-end: 2fr;
    grid-row-start: 1fr;
    grid-row-end: 3fr;

}

.topright {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 80px;
    grid-column-start: 2fr;
    grid-column-end: 3fr;
}

.bottomright {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 80px;
    grid-column-start: 2fr;
    grid-column-end: 3fr;
    grid-row-start: 2fr;
}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you can checkout TailwindCSS as it have some visual on it

Comment: -start and -end are unitless values for specifying position in the grid, not for sizing things which is what fr unit is for

Comment: The yellow exclamation marks tell you the reason why the property is crossed out. A site like [MDN CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) gives you insights what values are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your units are invalid. Rules like `grid-column-start` take a number (e.g. 1) and you're giving it values with units like `1fr`.

It doesn't start at column "1 fraction of the available space", it starts at column 1.

```css
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 2;
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 3;
```